# Regex to validate text field which can contain number and alphabets both

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, regular-expressions, lightning-inputfield

I want to validate an input text field using pattern. I want my field to contain 0-9 a-z A-Z

Please help pointing out the error in below code for the same

```
 <lightning-input type="text" name="state" maxlength="255" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]" value={state}  ></lightning-input>
```

But the field shows below error

```
Your entry does not match the allowed pattern.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. But looks like you need an * after.

```
<lightning-input type="text" name="state" maxlength="255" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]*" value={state}  ></lightning-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is here to check the syntax on the LWC javascript side (like me)...

```
let yourRegex = /Account\/(.*?)\/view/;
let path = window.location.pathname;
console.log(path.search(yourRegex));//returns the index if exists, otherwise -1
console.log(path.match(yourRegex));//returns all the occurrences if exists
console.log(yourRegex.test(path));//returns true if found a match
```

Comment: I cannot tell if this is an answer, a comment or a question. It does not seem like an answer as the original question was for Regex that allows alphanumerics, and your post is for "Account*". Please elaborate.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/186953)